# Flux linkage of 2 coils in series

Tags: electric-circuits, magnetic-fields

I have a question about magnetic circuits. I am an engineering student, therefore I will neglect some minor errors.

There is a simple magnetic circuit with 2 coils ($C_1$ & $C_2$), with $N_1$ & $N_2$ turns and $i_1$ & $i_2$ currents. Coils are in series and connected with 1 magnetic core of "O" shape (we may assume some reluctance in form of air gap = $R_c$). The [flux linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_linkage) of $C_1$ is as follows:

$$
\lambda_1 = N_1 \Phi= N_1 \left(\frac{N_1 i_1}{R_c} + \frac{N_2 i_2}{R_c}\right)
$$

so in the end I got something like

$$
\lambda_1=N_1^2i_1\left(\cdots\right)+N_1N_2i_i\left(\cdots\right)
$$

The $(\cdots)$ are some constants regarding air gap and core geometry.

I know that magnetic circuit resembles electric circuits. If there would be similar circuit with 2 batteries in series and 1 resistor, the overall voltage would be $V = V_1 + V_2$

In above mentioned magnetic circuit the overall flux linkage would be
\begin{align}
\lambda_{tot}&=\lambda_1+\lambda_2\\
&=N_1^2i_1\left(\cdots\right)+N_2^2i_2\left(\cdots\right)+2N_1N_2i_2\left(\cdots\right)
\end{align}

My questions are then

1. Why is there the term $2N_1N_2 i_2(...)$ in the last part?
2. Why is the electric circuit $V = V_1 + V_2$ and no $V_{12}$?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there the term $2N_1N_2i_2$(...) in the last part?

Two [coupled inductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Coupled_inductors_and_mutual_inductance) are not **two** two-terminal circuit elements but, rather, **one** [two-port network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network), e.g.

[image]

where

$$M = k\sqrt{L_1L_2} $$

thus, the reason for the $N_1N_2$ terms.  Note that as the coupling $k$ goes to zero, we recover the two independent inductors.

Comment: You say that as $k$ tends to 0 we recover two independent inductors. What then happens with the M attached to the ground rail?

Comment: @Urgje, M is zero when k is zero, i.e., the middle inductor is a short circuit.  However, there is no ground rail in that drawing.

Comment: The circuit you posted cannot be used to say that two coupled inductors form a two-port network. In fact, the circuit shown is a circuit which is equivalent to two coupled inductors, but only when the two inductors have, or can have, a terminal in common, _and the two-port condition is imposed externally_.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that magnetic circuit resembles electric circuits.

Yes, but the analogy works between certain specific quantities, and you are considering the wrong ones: the electromotive force does not correspond to the flux linkage, but to the magnetomotive force.

For lumped magnetic and electric circuits, the main correspondences are as follows:

Magnetomotive force $\mathcal{M}$ $\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad$ Electromotive force $E$

Magnetic flux $\varPhi$ $\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad$ Electric current $I$

Magnetic reluctance $\mathcal{R}$ $\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad$ Electric resistance $R$

Only with these correspondences the magnetic analogues of the Kirchhoff's voltage and current laws hold (see also [Magnetic circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit) on Wikipedia).

In the case of your circuit, the total magnetomotive force is $\mathcal{M} = N_1i_1+N_2i_2 = \mathcal{M}_1+\mathcal{M}_2$, and there isn't any cross-term.